# how to choose the best machine learning algorithms from all kinds of algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model, model-selection

guys, I am a beginner at data science and I’ve been learning machine learning for a while with some courses online without any help of a teacher and after I’ve got to work with some real projects on my own, I have found some questions and couldn’t find the answers so if you be could help me in this problem and guide me to a better path, I would be thankful,
Here is my question:
When I want to find a model for my dataset that I find that there are lots of algorithms that I can use.
I know how to minimize selection choices by separating supervised and unsupervised algorithms and the purpose of the problem I am trying to solve.
But after that, there are also lots of algorithms to choose from, even in the sklearn library that I currently use, and there are lots of algorithms that I don’t know and there might work better in my problem and also there are deep learning algorithms that are stronger than machine learning algorithms and after looking for them I’ve got tired and a simple project cost me whole 2 weeks but I wasn’t satisfied with the result at the end neither.
So, what should I do?
Do I have to memorize all the algorithms in machine learning libraries like sklearn?
Or should I abandon learning machine learning algorithms and start learning deep learning?

Comment: What’s your objective ?

Comment: please dont post same question multiple times https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/104318/how-to-choose-the-best-machine-learning-algorithms-from-all-kinds-of-algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Here are some important considerations while choosing an algorithm.

1. Size of the training data
2. Accuracy and/or Interpretability of the output
3. Speed or Training time
4. Linearity
5. Number of features